# os.listdir outputting different files than there are in the folder

Tags: python, file-io

here is my code sample:

```
if os.path.exists(inputdir):
    for file in os.listdir(inputdir):
        print file
```

So when I print the files, files that do not actually exist in the input directory are printed so when I try to use the file it cannot open it. What could be causing this issue?

EDIT:
Out of 8,831 files at the beginning this gets printed:

```
0004872bda8db3ea40167b887108e9a3.xml
0007cba714860a090922cec6132442a4.xml
0009f949eba51c5d2936458595040135.xml
```

When the actual files are:

```
000cbd88e8868d56aa7eb7a7e3e90166.xml
00a270aa4d18f139d0405604df200c61.xml
00a39768b77e83f86bd3cd81bf5a9cfb.xml
```

And at the end the files are identical. I'm not sure at what point it changes.

Comment: Might be an issue with the run-time path being on the front end of those paths.

Comment: Could we see the output ? It could be that another script is working with files in the same folder.

Comment: Here's more detail: what's strange is that some of the files are printed exactly as they are, but most files are not, but the number of files is identical as well.

Comment: Do you recognize these files?

Comment: I mean they look almost identical and I looked in other folders for these files but they don't exist.

Comment: Are you trying to open the file in the loop? If so you probably need `os.path.join`

Comment: You sure it's not a sorting artefact?

Comment: Right now  I am just printing out the name of the files

Comment: @Ana, what happens if you try to open each file?

Comment: I checked for those top files -- they don't exist. In both cases the output is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Something must be accessing that directory? What is creating those 8000 odd files?

Comment: They were copied there manually by me. 

@Padraic 
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0004872bda8db3ea40167b887108e9a3.xml'

Comment: BTW, "file" is a builtin type, rather use a different variable name

Comment: you need to join the path `with open(os.path.join("the_path",f))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Ana is printing the filenames from listdir, not opening them

Comment: @Will, I am aware of that but the files apparently don't exist after so if they don't exist you wouldn't be able to open then, at least if the .xml files are opened it might shed some light on what is happening

Comment: EDIT: nevermind it is still trying to use that file that doesn't exist :(

Comment: @Ana, so it errors trying to open?

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
import os
for entry in sorted(os.listdir(inputdir)):
  filename = os.path.join(inputdir, entry)
  print(filename)
  os.lstat(filename)
```

If your system doesn't have `os.lstat`, then try `os.stat`.

One possible reason why you are getting `No such file or directory` is that `filename` is a symlink pointing to a nonexisting file.